# Is there an app that allows multiple-stops itinerary on public transport?

Tags: public-transport, mobile-apps

I am looking for an app that allows you to construct multiple-stop itinerary on + in one query :

```
A -- B # What is possible
A -- C -- B # What I am looking for
```

[Google Maps](https://maps.google.com) only allow those by car, foot and bike.
Both [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/) and [Transit](https://transitapp.com/) don't support it.

And neither of the local networks' app that I use have that possibility.

Is there an app/website, preferably widespread (local answers are welcome nevertheless), that allow for such itinerary on public transport?

As an aside, I was wondering if there is a technical barrier to implementing such solution?

Comment: Citymapper does do this. I use it for this exact purpose in London - now it isn't entirely flexible, and only offers stops and routes that "make sense" but it is pretty effective.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm pretty sure this is London-exclusive, as their *birthplace*, but every network in the EU I have tried doesn't support it, might be a good sign for a widening deployment though

Comment: That is why I only offered it as a comment, not an answer - sorry I can't be more helpful. I haven't seen any other app in this space.

Comment: You need to say where you need this? Like Citymapper apparently does for London, Rejseplanen does do this for travel internally in Denmark (it's very internal, last week I had a suggested journey where the last part was on a train that crossed the border into Germany, they listed the last stop in Denmark as the destination - I wasn't going that far, so it just caused a bit of confusion on whether I had found the correct train)

Comment: What exactly would you expect to get from such a feature that you cannot find out by looking up both segments separately? A -- C -- B is very different from A -- C + C -- B in international air transport because the fares can be very different and there are important consequences of booking the whole itinerary as one ticket but none of these apply to local public transit.

Answer (score 5):

I think Rome2rio offers what you are looking for, although I have no idea how optimal the choices are. For instance I tried a slightly random journey within Italy and Switzerland and the result sounded plausible enough (it involved trains, buses and ferries).

You add each leg separately, rather than say you wish to travel from A to B via C.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In The Netherlands both the [9292 planner](https://9292.nl/) and the planner of [NS](https://www.ns.nl/en) (the main train company) allow for 1 extra stop:

**9292**:

[image: Screenshot of 9292.nl planner showing 1 intermediate stop at Utrecht Centraal]

**NS**:

[image: Screenshot of NS planner showing 1 intermediate stop at Utrecht Centraal]

For rail travel in Europe the Deutsche Bahn planner allows to choose 1 or 2 stopovers.

**DB**:

[image: Advanced planner of DB showing the option to choose 1 or 2 intermediate stops.]

Comment: I think most national rail and/or bus planners allow something like this but most of them only do the combination within their country or at most just over de borders, some do only do them for buses or trains and not for both. The German planner does it very well for the combination within Germany but does not know the buses over the borders.